# How can I draw a single sprite at random positions 10 times?

Tags: c#, random, xna, position, sprite

Im totally new at this and have a question. I worked with an exercise in school and at home but I can't figure out how to do it.

The thing is I want to draw a single sprite at 10 random positions on the screen without using a special sprite class. My problem is that after they are drawn they vanish again.

Solved it, thanks for all the help!

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Texture2D turtleTexture;
    int counter = 0;
    Random randomera = new Random();
    int x;
    int y;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";        
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        turtleTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/turtle_50x38");
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

         /*
         if(counter < 10)
         {
             x = randomera.Next(600);
            y = randomera.Next(400);
            counter++;
         }
         */

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);


        if (counter < 10)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(turtleTexture, new Vector2(randomera.Next(600), randomera.Next(400)),
                    Color.Black);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep previous frames visible while you draw more sprites?

Comment: This might be better suited in [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why there is `if(counter < 10)` in your code, if there is `for` loop which counts to 10 after that?

Comment: I just want 10 sprites to be drawned at different position and then stay there

Comment: @Bartosz I thought that without the "if(counter < 10) the loop would loop 10 times then go back to update and then back to draw and loop 10 times again

Comment: I'd also add that you should not be doing any kind of "processing" in your Draw function beyond drawing the sprites. This kind of code belongs in the Update function.

Comment: Ah, now I know, the `if(counter < 10)` was way to not repeat sprite drawing. But they got cleared in next frame, hence problem was not solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have your sprites on the same random positions all the time and still clearing your viewport (for example, you may want to render other content) you may just reset the random seed every frame to the same value:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    randomera = new Random(seed);   
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);


    if (counter < 10)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(turtleTexture, new Vector2(randomera.Next(600), randomera.Next(400)),
                Color.Black);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

where the seed should be randomly generated in your `Initialize()` method, and not be changed after that.

You may also just initialize list with predefined coords:

```
List<Vector2> coords = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new Vector2(randomera.Next(600), randomera.Next(400)).ToList();
```

and use this list in your drawing routine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(turtleTexture, coords[i],
        Color.Black);
}
```

Comment: This technically works, but wouldn't it make more sense to generate an array of 10 Vectors in the constructor and then use those? This would have the added benefit of being easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Exactly, and I was in the middle of modyfing my answer to reflect that. Now it's there as well. I guess that I just wanted to be random-seed smartass;)

Comment: I would shy away from the first approach all together. I cannot imagine any scenarios where this would be a good idea. The second is much better. In the future, it would be much easier to exercise more control of the array, such as starting the turtles in random position but then having them move about the screen, etc.

Comment: Yeah, setting seed might be useful with some semi-procedural approaches, and during scene setting phase, not while drawing.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
```

This clears the screen (meaning anything previously drawn will be erased). The Draw function in which this statement is contained is called roughly 30 to 60 times per second, and your randomizer will fetch new values on each of these iterations.

It is correct to clear the screen on each Draw iteration, so rather than choosing random coordinates on each call to Draw, determine the coordinates before hand. A better approach might be to initialize an array of 10 Vectors in your constructor, then use that array in your Draw function (rather than calling `randomera.Next()` over and over).

**EDIT:** (See the second half of Bartosz's answer for an example. I'm not able to open my XNA IDE at the moment, so I can't write out the code example for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Clear` in your draw method

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
```

This will clear the screen.

Remove this line and it will keep the previous drawn stuff.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You will fill up your screen with sprites in extremely short order since your Draw function will be called 30 times per second or more.

Comment: @Cyborgx37  I dont think you read his code properly. It will draw 10 sprites, and then cease drawing. This fixes his problem

Comment: Yes, you are correct... I missed that part. But removing the `Clear` function from the application is still a bad idea. It goes against best practice for an XNA game and will hobble any future use of this application. I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: @Cyborgx37. Yes. Everything he draws will be persistant. He needs to restructure how he is approaching it. Initialising the coordinates on startup is a good idea and Bartosz has already answered with this, so I gave +1 to him. :)